# Automatic Spell Checker for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any spell checker (or plugin) for `Xcode` that will *automatically* spell check all my strings? 
e.g.

```
self.label.text = @"Spell check this";
```

Comment: To check the spelling on labels displayed to the users.

Comment: I'm quite clear on what you want such a feature to do, but _why_ is what I'm unclear about. You're concerned about checking the spelling of a string - something that is not going to impact the functionality of the application, all other things being correct. If you can't assure yourself of the spelling of something trivial I'd be more concerned about the things that do impact functionality.

Comment: I filed radar 17572630 to check variable names. Code should be easy to read and part of that is correct spelling. This is especially important given the convention of huge function and variable names in Cocoa (Touch). It sounds like something Apple would care about and they'll figure something out.

Comment: I dont use xCode anymore, but AppCode does that no probs.

Answer (score 19):

You don't need a plugin for this, you just have to turn on "Check Spelling While Typing"

**Edit > Format > Spelling and Grammar > Check Spelling While Typing**

[image]

Comment: This is underlining keywords like `func` for me in Swift.

Comment: Xcode 10 this menu is disabled for me. odd. can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Scribe plugin](https://scribeplugin.com) can do that (among other things).  You can set it to just check strings, or check both strings and comments.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of the plugin.

Comment: its not free, and does it only checks comments?

Comment: @meda It can check any combination of comments, strings and code.  You can turn any of them on/off in the preferences.  More importantly, it helps you *fix* the spelling by right-clicking.  And yes, it's not free, but it's very cheap.  I'm sure the price is worth it to any team and to most individuals.  Any manager would approve the spend.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you write in quotes,is treated as string.

**XCode is not a word processor**, and it may be some method name, selectors, password, so there is no way that any IDE will provide you spell check.

The compiler does have a spell check for variables, not for constant strings.

Even if you want then here is something for you :

**Edit -> Format -> Spelling and Grammar -> Check Document Now (cmd + ;)**

Comment: Nice Answer, To the point.

Comment: @Matt: But for what use, question has more votes than combined votes on answers. :)

Comment: Matter of interests to the readers, I assume :)

Comment: @bobics: The question is for Xcode not AppCode.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Non sequitur - "XCode is not a word processor, and it may be some method name, selectors, password, so there is no way that any IDE will provide you spell check."  This is false.

Comment: @bobics: "Even if you want........ Spelling and Grammer..." is also mentioned there.